# Aligning two divs with header div

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm trying to get a layout to look like this following:

http://i42.tinypic.com/2i8wyrk.png

I've managed to get the "content" div aligned fine with the header div, but I'm not sure how to put the nav div in there and keep it aligned properly. This is what I have so far:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
div#container {
    position: relative;
}
body {
    background-color: #121212
}
div#header {
    background-color: #900;
    width: 70%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 2px solid #488ed0;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
div#nav {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #900;
    border: 2px solid #488ed0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
div#content {

    border: 2px solid #488ed0;
    background-color: #900;
    width: 70%;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #000000; 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "container">
<div id="header">
<center><img src = "images/logo.png" /></center>
</div>
<br />
<div id="nav">
<center><br />
<a href='#'>Index</a><br />
<a href='#'>About</a><br />
<a href='#'>Contact</a>
</center>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I align the nav div as it is in the example mockup I made? I want to make sure the left side of 'nav' stays aligned with the header, and the right side of 'content' stays aligned with the right side of the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution if you're looking for a liquid layout: http://jsfiddle.net/M78q4/1/

HTML

```
<div id="head">this</div>
<div id="container">
   <div id="nav"></div><div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
    background-color: #121212
}
div#header {
    background-color: #900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 2px solid #488ed0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
div#nav {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #900;
    border: 2px solid #488ed0;
    width: 24%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
div#content {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #488ed0;
    background-color: #900;
    width: 74%;
    height: 900px;
    float: left;
}
a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #000000; 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If you don't want it to be liquid just change the #container width to a fixed width like 800px. Adjust the margins as needed.

Comment: This works beautifully! No idea what the -moz-box-sizing bits are, though; what should I look up to learn more about that?

Comment: This is just a little piece of magic =]: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

For nav I noticed that you are using `position: absolute` and a `float: left;`. While aligning might need a bit of tweaking the best solution I can think of is using `float` for both the nav and content. For example:

```
#header{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
}

#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
}

#nav{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}

#content{
    float: right;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
 }
```

Of course adjust the widths, height and margins according to the spacing you would like.

```
<div id="header">This is my banner</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">This is my navigation menu</div>
    <div id="content">This is my content</div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
```

If you want to make sure that things stay aligned when adding a margin to the nav section use `margin-right` and if you want to add a margin to the content section use `margin-left`. Finally, if you need a space between the banner and the two section below it use `margin-bottom` inside the `header` CSS.

Comment: This is a good start. I tried it out, and it makes the nav bar all the way against the left side of the page, while the right side of the content div is pushed against the right side of the page; the header remains centered.From here should I mess around with margin-left and margin-right to get them lined up properly under the header?

Comment: I apologize, let me update my code. You will need to create a container. This container will hold the nav and content CSS. Updating now!

Answer (score 0):

This should get the layout you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/WDvwP/

**HTML**

```
<div id="head"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav"></div><div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#head{
    width:900px; height:100px;
    background:#f00;
    margin:10px auto;
}
#container{
     width:900px; margin:0 auto;
}
#nav{
    display:inline-block;
    width:250px; height:300px;
    background:#0f0;
}
#content{
    display:inline-block;
    width:600px; height:300px;
    background:#00f;
    margin:0 0 0 50px;
}
```